# Curvature of the composition between a rigid motion and a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Consider the following problem (Exercise 1.18 in the book *Curves and Surfaces*, by Montiel and Ros)

> Let $\alpha : I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular curve parametrized by the arc length. Let $M$ be a rigid motion. Let $\beta = M \circ \alpha$. Show that 
>   $$
> k_\beta(s) = \begin{cases}
> k_\alpha(s) \quad \text{ if } M \text{ is direct } \\
> - k_\alpha(s) \quad \text{ if } M \text{ is inverse }
> \end{cases},
> $$
>   where $k$ denotes the curvature.

Now, $M$ being a rigid motion is of the form $Mx = Ax + b$. Then
$$
k_\beta(s) = \det(\beta'(s), \beta''(s)) = \det((M \circ \alpha)'(s), (M \circ \alpha)''(s)) = \det(A\alpha'(s), A\alpha''(s)).
$$
The result suggests that we should be able to write $k_\beta(s) = \det A \det(\alpha'(s), \alpha''(s))$, but I cannot see why is this true.

Any hints will be the most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! Just note that if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ then
$$
(Ax,Ay) = A(x,y).
$$
Indeed, write
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}, \quad x=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix} ,\qquad y= \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then
$$
(Ax,Ay) = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2 & a_{11}y_1 + a_{12}y_2\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2 & a_{21}y_1+a_{22}y_2
\end{pmatrix} = A=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1\\
x_2 & y_2
\end{pmatrix} = A(x,y).
$$
So, we have that
$$
\det(Ax,Ay) = \det(A(x,y)) = \det(A)\det(x,y).
$$
With this,
$$
\det(A(\alpha'(s),A\alpha''(s))) = \det(A)\det(\alpha'(s),\alpha''(s)),
$$
as desired.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking of $(x, y)$ as the matrix with lines $x$ and $y$, instead of columns. Thanks a lot.